# Normalize function in fenics

Tags: integration, fenics

I have a function in fenics which is defined on product function space (for real and imaginary parts). Now I want to compute the integral of this function over the domain. I have no glue how this should work. And I am not able to find something in the documentation. I think the documentation has changed this week since non of the google links is working anymore.
The Function space is defined as follows:

> FuncSpace = FiniteElement( "CG" , mesh.ufl_cell() ,  1 )
>
> FuncSpace2 = FunctionSpace( mesh , MixedElement( [ FuncSpace , FuncSpace ] )

And the function is defined as:

> Psi = Function( FuncSpace2 )

I am solving some partial integration problem and afterwards want to compute the integral of this function.
Can anyone help me with this problem I am quite stuck?

Or can I convert the function to some python array because then I the integration would be straightforward

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the answer now.
First I split the result function Psi into real and complex part

> Real , Imag = split( Psi )

next I define the abs value of the function by:

> absPsi = sqrt( Real * Real + Imag * Imag )

Now I have to define a measure on the used mesh:

> ds = Measure( "dx" , domain = mesh )

where mesh contains a mesh defined by fenics.
And last the integral is solved by:

> norm = assemble( d * ds )